AWS Cognito w React.js localhost CORS error
I’ve seen similar issues when searching - but let’s assume I’m using AWS sample code to setup Cognito in React.  Set callback / signout URI to http://localhost:3000 which is literally stated by AWS to be the one exception to needing https. Now I’m not at my workstation - but I’m pretty sure I’ve tried not using the port, but can’t see what I’m missing as I see no reason for the CORS issue as I’m not doing anything but testing login.  There is no other setting in Cognito console for CORS I’m missing I don’t think - but my hosted UI link within Cognito works - just how this code calls it.  Thanks for any guidance, I just don’t want to go into production just to test and develop.  Is it my browser?  I’m going to use Amplify which I’ve seen manages CORS but this one feels just weird.  Thanks for any support!


// index.js
import { AuthProvider } from "react-oidc-context";

const cognitoAuthConfig = {
  authority: "https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-secretStuff(user pool)",
  client_id: "secretStuff client id",
  redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000",
  response_type: "code",
  scope: "email openid phone",
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));

// wrap the application with AuthProvider
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AuthProvider {...cognitoAuthConfig}>
      <App />
    </AuthProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

Edited out account stuff with secretStuff but those are verified.. but do note for authority it’s just ends with user pool ID.
Next up is app.js

// App.js

import { useAuth } from "react-oidc-context";

function App() {
  const auth = useAuth();

  const signOutRedirect = () => {
    const clientId = "secretStuff client ID";
    const logoutUri = "http://localhost:3000";
    const cognitoDomain = "https://us-east-secretStuff.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com";
    window.location.href = `${cognitoDomain}/logout?client_id=${clientId}&logout_uri=${encodeURIComponent(logoutUri)}`;
  };

  if (auth.isLoading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  if (auth.error) {
    return <div>Encountering error... {auth.error.message}</div>;
  }

  if (auth.isAuthenticated) {
    return (
      <div>
        <pre> Hello: {auth.user?.profile.email} </pre>
        <pre> ID Token: {auth.user?.id_token} </pre>
        <pre> Access Token: {auth.user?.access_token} </pre>
        <pre> Refresh Token: {auth.user?.refresh_token} </pre>

        <button onClick={() => auth.removeUser()}>Sign out</button>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => auth.signinRedirect()}>Sign in</button>
      <button onClick={() => signOutRedirect()}>Sign out</button>
    </div>
  );
}
  
export default App;


Found the solution -
Pay close attention to this:
const oidcConfig = {
authority: "https://us-east-*********.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com",
client_id: "secretStuff",
redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000",
response_type: "code",
scope: "openid email phone",};

My authority for whatever reason was using my Cognito Domain.  I’m not sure anyone could of solved this without seeing my account info.
For posterity - the oidc / authority url looks a bit different, which the user group ID is at the end:
"https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_exAMpLe"

Hope this helps anyone randomly searching the same issue.
